# Parse iOS SDK: Refresh PFQueryTableViewController upon new object

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform

**Scenario** = I have an app with a messaging feature. A PFQueryTableViewController that will display the contents of the messages in the table. When a new message is sent, I want the **recipients** table view on their app to refresh, showing the newly added message from the sender.

**Question** = I am assuming there needs to be a query done to continuously count how many messages have the same associated ID and if there is one more than the last time it check, than does "self loadObjects". Is this even the right idea?

```
-(void)callAfterFiveSecond:(NSTimer *)timer {

    PFQuery *messageQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Message"];
    [messageQuery whereKey:@"messageID" equalTo:self.selectedMessageID];
    [messagesQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        if (objects.count > lastCount) {

            [self loadObjects];
        }

    }];

}
```

or should this maybe be some sort of a cloud function, if so what would you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this as a cloud function to save loading time, because you would be querying a lot to check for new messages. If you don't want to do this I can suggest an alternative query:

1. You would have to have a timer run every second or so to check for new messages.
2. Get the createdAt variable for the most recent object.
3. In the method that the timer calls, query for all objects that have a createdAt date after the most recent one already in the table, then reload the table to display the new chat messages.

Also, if you have a chat feature, you could look into using this library here: https://github.com/relatedcode/ParseChat

Comment: Hey Jacob thanks for the response! How would I write a cloud function such as that? Also, what would be the difference between doing a cloud code and what I've done above? Do cloud functions cost less on the "requests per sec" count?

Comment: @TomTesticool Well I would write a cloud code function that essentially does the same thing as what you've done. It would accept the most recent object's id as part of the data, query for objects created after that object, and return the results to the app. If it's done in the cloud it's not holding up anything else that is being done on the device, it all happens in the background. I'm not sure how this affects the rps count, but I'm sure there's something in the parse docs about this.

Comment: Ok, so to recap everything - I have the right idea with my code above, or at least you and I don't know of a better way to achieve this, but it needs to be done in a cloud function instead?

Comment: @TomTesticool Yes, to my knowledge that is the right idea. I'm actually working on a chat app now and that's the way I'm probably going to do it unless I can find a better way that doesn't involve querying the network so much. I don't know how realistic this is because in a live chat/messaging app, you have to constantly check for new messages :/

Comment: We are one you and I. I think this is the way to go as well. Thing is I hate JavaScript but now I got to get that down on lock too if I'm going to master the cloud code. Good luck on your app jake. I'll make you as answered but if anyone else out there has a better idea I'd love to hear it.

Comment: @TomTesticool haha thanks. I actually just started working with cloud code for my apps and it is fairly easy to get a hold of. Just trial and error! If you need any help with cloud code or JavaScript stuff let me know!

Comment: You got it. And I'll probably come calling because I'll need help for sure. Though what the hell was I thinking in my code though. If my queryForTable method already querys for the message ID then why in my method above did I query for it again? I probably should have just said self loadObjects and then be done with it. Why the need for the cloud code or any of it?

Comment: Haha I was thinking about that when I typed my answer but I figured you were handling it some other way. Good luck!

Comment: My bad pressed enter mid sentence and commented too soon

Comment: Haha yea that works too. Well I guess it was good to talk out the problem anyway lol